# Ionic + CreateJs high CPU and Memory

Tags: ionic-framework, createjs

I have a serious problem with an increasing CPU and RAM usage in an ionic app with createjs  library. The problem cause the app to crash after a while.
As I am navigating between pages where each page has a new canvas, I see the RAM and CPU to dramatically increase.
There is no memory leak. I have tested it with chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After so so much testing, the solution was to treat each template page in ionic as a root page. So when I was navigating to a new template page I always did:

```
          $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
            historyRoot: true,
            disableBack: true
          });

          $ionicHistory.clearCache();
          createjs.Tween.removeAllTweens();
          $scope.stage.removeAllEventListeners();
          $scope.stage.removeAllChildren();
          $state.go("lesson", {}, {reload: true});
```

This way all cache that ionic kept was cleared and every event, tween motion and element in createjs was cleared too.
This increased the speed of the app drammatically!